# Sitecore User Group Dec 2018 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked pumped to announce the December meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Three excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

1. Driving an immersive customer experience with Sitecore Experience Commerce + IoT by Jason Wilkerson - Sitecore MVP / Sitecore Architect at Wilkerson Consulting Inc
2. Using SiteCron by Akshay Sura - Sitecore MVP @Konabos Consulting
3. Modern loyalty programs - Experience Commerce & Email Experience Manager (from a developer perspective) by Kamruz Jaman and Akshay Sura - Sitecore MVP @Konabos Consulting

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Dec, 12, 2018 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Dec, 12, 2018 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/256410309/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Dec 2 at 22:00